# How would you say you are not looking forward to something?

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire

Another weird one, but how would you say you're not looking forward to a certain day? For instance, if you were not looking forward to Easter (since its coming soon haha), would it be something like "je n'ai pas hâte à Pâques" or something entirely different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close. Something like this would do

> Je n'ai pas hâte d'être à Pâques.

Comment: I don't think you can say être à [holiday] like that.  It's not idiomatic in French.

Comment: Too bad then that so many french people are using it, isn't it?

Comment: Franchement? être à Pâques? être à Noel? être aux vacances? Et non.

Comment: @Lambie je tiens a vous corriger, nous disons "être en vacances".

Comment: Vous n'avez pas compris mon sarcasme? On ne dit pas "avoir hâte d'être à [x]. C'était pour montrer le ridicule de la chose...

Comment: Il n'y a pas de mal.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to your near miss in your question and the good accepted answer, the following constructions could also capture the general sentiment of "not looking forward to something":

> **Je ne suis pas pressé(e)** **de** voir Pâques [arriver]. ('I’m not in a
>   hurry to see Easter come.')

or

> **Je n’ai pas** vraiment **envie** **de** voir Pâques arriver. ('I really don’t
>   want Easter to come.')

or

> **Ça ne me dit rien** **de** voir Pâques arriver. ('I don't care much about
>   the coming of Easter.')

The following one would probably be hyperbolic exaggeration and probably not extremely suitable when discussing religious holidays (unless one is terrified of some of the unbelievable paranormal events historically associated with these holidays, e.g., egg-bearing rabbits; chocolate-bearing flying bells; red-suited intruders descending chimneys), but I’ve heard Students use it at Summer’s end:

> **J’ai la hantise de** La Rentrée ('I absolutely dread the beginning of
>   school' [which in most cases actually just means 'I’m not looking
>   forward to the end of Summer']).

Comment: Thanks, @Amphiteóth for pointing it out & Charlie for fixing it!  I was so proud of remembering the circumflex that I forgot that it wasn’t spelled like “Jacques”! “Appréhender” certainly works well to express the opposite of “avoir hâte” w/out having to use “ne pas” (& w/out having to exaggerate like with “avoir la hantise”). I wasn’t even aware of this 2d meaning of the verb (in either French OR English), meaning that I’ve been using its root to express this “anxiety” notion all my life in my own language as a noun (apprehension) & an adjective (apprehensive) w/out even knowing why! Thanks!

Comment: You're most welcome!

Answer (score 1):

> Je n'ai pas hâte à Pâques.

Indeed *avoir hâte à + (nom, infinitif)* is simply more usual in Québec (see "hâte" in *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, sous la dir. d'A. Rey, ed. *Le Robert*), but correct nevertheless.